# Turn a repeated foreach loop to a method so that it's only repeated once

Tags: c#, methods, foreach

So, my issue here may turn out to be simple. I know how to create a method to callback from the application, but my issue is trying to figure out how to do it properly in this manner. I need to take the foreach loop that is repeated :(foreach (Ticket t in events)
            {
                if (t.getName().Equals(cbEvents.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
) 
 and change it to a method to be called on twice in the code. Please help. Code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TicketPurchasing
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ArrayList events;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        events = new ArrayList();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create events
        events.Add(new Game(12.00, "KSU vs UGA", "Convocation Building",   "bball", "Basketball"));
        events.Add(new Game(15.00, "KSU vs GSU", "Stadium", "fball", "Football"));
        events.Add(new Concert(8.00, "Country Music", "Campus Green", "hayes", "Hunter Hayes"));
        events.Add(new Concert(12.00, "Rock/Pop", "Campus Green", "m5", "Maroon5"));

        //Load combobox
        foreach (Ticket t in events)
        {
            cbEvents.Items.Add(t.getName());
        }
    }

    private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get name of selected item from combobox
        string eventName;

        //Traverse array to determine the match
        foreach (Ticket t in events)
        {
            if (t.getName().Equals(cbEvents.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                //Display details
                lblDetails.Text = t.getDetails();

                //Display image
                displayImage(t.getFileName());
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayImage(string file)
    {
        Size size = new Size(173, 180);
        Image img = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(file);
        img = (Image)(new Bitmap(img, size));
        pbImage.Image = img;
        pbImage.Refresh();
        pbImage.Visible = true;
    }

    private void txtTickets_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get number of tickets

        int num = int.Parse(txtTickets.Text);

        double ticketCost = 0;

        //Get cost of ticket
        foreach (Ticket t in events)
        {
            if (t.getName().Equals(cbEvents.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                ticketCost = t.getCost();
            }
        }

        //Calculate cost
        double total = num * ticketCost;

        //Display cost
        txtCost.Text = total.ToString("c");
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Exit the application
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear all information
        lblDetails.Text = "";
        pbImage.Image = null;
        txtTickets.Text = "0";
        txtCost.Text = "";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? You want to encapsulate your foreach code into a reusable method or just make the if case reusable?

Comment: do you mean you just need to refactor it so you can call dothis or whatever?

Comment: you can call a method with a delegate. and in the method you loop through the elements and just invoke the delegate. the delegate can contain your code lines within your foreach blocks.

Comment: My issue is although the forloop is used twice, they call different things. When its first used, the foreach loop gets "details" and "file name". The second time it gets "ticket cost". Being instructed to make a method that does uses foreach loop once then have it called twice. That makes no sense to me. – Byron Buyck just now   edit   delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
    private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get name of selected item from combobox
        string eventName;

        //Traverse array to determine the match
        MethodAfterRefactor(() => 
        {
            //Display details
            lblDetails.Text = t.getDetails();

            //Display image
            displayImage(t.getFileName());
        });
    }

    private void MethodAfterRefactor(Func<object> p)
    {
        foreach (Ticket t in events)
        {
            if (t.getName().Equals(cbEvents.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                p.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that, except my issue is although the forloop is used twice, they call different things. When its first used, the foreach loop gets "details" and "file name". The second time it gets "ticket cost". Being instructed to make a method that does uses foreach loop once then have it called twice. That makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking about this slightly differently, let's start by working out what you really want to do.

You have two lists, one represents the View artefacts `cbEvents`, the other the data behind that (sometimes known as the ViewModel) `events`.

What you are trying to do is match your ViewModel from your View because you *only* put the name into the view.

If you instead put your ViewModel into your View so that it can be rendered as just the name, then this code goes away. Something like

```
public class Ticket
{
    ...

   public string override ToString() { return getName(); }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     //Load combobox
    foreach (Ticket t in events)
    {
        cbEvents.Items.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Then you can do stuff like

```
private void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Ticket t = cbEvents.SelectedItem as Ticket;
    if (t !=null)
    {
            //Display details
            lblDetails.Text = t.getDetails();

            //Display image
            displayImage(t.getFileName());            
    }
}
```

This is obviously a totally different way of thinking about this but is much easier.  You may also find that some controls don't support binding to the object so well, in which case (at least in WinForms) you can use the `Tag` field

```
 lblText.Text = t.getName();
 lblText.Tag = t;
```

or in WPF the `DataContext` so you then bind to the fields e.g.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I think I may have it figured out because of you all's help!!